# VBA Loop not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am new to writing VBA and not sure to to complete this loop. I am reading down a column and identifying the cell color. If the cell color is correct then i preform the action. The problem is that action pastes that info into cell N7. That is where my loop gets messed up because i need it to go the cell A9 next. Can some one explain what the next step would be. I  know that need to put that cell A8 in a loop and increase by 1 each time but not sure how to do that.

```
Range("A8").Select

    Do
        If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(79, 129, 189) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("N7").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        ElseIf ActiveCell.Select = "BREAK" Then
            Exit Sub

        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish when you identify the color. Could you add more explanation there?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion. So in column "A" i have titles that are in blue and data below those titles. Below each title is rows of data vary. That is why i have the offsets I have the marco read down for the title (cell in blue) copy the data and paste it to cell N7. Then i want that macro to go back to Cell A8 and move down one and repeat. If  that cell is not blue then go down one more. If it finds another cell that is blue copy the data to N7 BUT to the last blank cell in that column. The code below sorta works but over writes the previous data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** updated script below to copy data per additional comments

`.Select` and `.Activate` are common sources of run-time errors and can likely be avoided in this case. Though I'm not really clear on the action you're trying to take when you identify the color in column A, you could use the following heavily-commented script to accomplish the "loop-and-check-for-BREAK" action.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ProcessColumnA()

Dim Counter As Long
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range, DestCell As Range

'set references up-front
Counter = 8
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Cell = MySheet.Cells(Counter, 1)
Set DestCell = MySheet.Cells(7, 14)

'loop on column A until we find "BREAK" or
'counter is greater than 10K, whichever comes first
Do Until Cell.Value = "BREAK" Or Counter > 10000

    'check color and take action if necessary
    If Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(79, 129, 189) Then

        'do the copy work here
        Cell.Copy Destination:=DestCell

        'increment the destination cell
        Set DestCell = DestCell.Offset(1, 0)

    End If

    'increment the counter variable and set the next cell
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Set Cell = MySheet.Cells(Counter, 1)

Loop

'send user a message regarding the results
If Counter > 10000 Then
    MsgBox ("Whoa you hit 10K cells before finding 'BREAK'...")
Else
    MsgBox ("Processing complete!")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the Fix. I understand what you are saying about .select and .Activate. I will for sure keep that in mind while i continue to learn VBA